# in mysql is it possible to sort results using one columns of a table if not empty or another table column

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have those two tables, Artist and Pseudonym, Artist belongsTo Pseudonym

I'd like to join the two tables and sort the result on Artist.lastname. Now, if he has a pseudonym, the pseudonym should be used, like in the example below, Balthus is between BACON and CHAGAL, even if his lastname starts with K

```
Artist.Lastname     Pseudonym.name
BACON
KLOSSOWSKI          Balthus
CHAGAL
CEZANNE
```

Is it possible to make a virtual column that has the pseudo if not empty or the lastname, and then sort on that column?

```
SELECT .....
FROM Artists as a
LEFT JOIN Pseudonyms as p ON (a.pseudonym_id = p.id)
ORDER BY the_virtual_column
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you add "IF" statement in PHP MYSQL ORDER BY?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550942/can-you-add-if-statement-in-php-mysql-order-by)

Comment: First of all thank you all. I'll check also the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
...ORDER BY COALESCE(p.name, a.Lastname)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT ..... 
  FROM Artists as a LEFT JOIN Pseudonyms as p 
    ON (a.pseudonym_id = p.id) 
 ORDER BY COALESCE(p.name , a.Lastname)
```