# Order by column if column exists else order by id

Tags: mysql

Hello is it possible to make an ordered select statement in MYSQL where the user will select the column name to be ordered by. I know that I can make a list of predefined choices for the user but the user has the option to create his own columns for each table.

At first I was thinking to check if the column is inside the results of a query like:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_database' AND TABLE_NAME = 'my_table';
```

or

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM my_table;
```

but I'd like like a cleaner solution for this and I'm not so proficient with mysql.
In other words:

```
SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE users.id = 'user_id' ORDER BY 'column' IF EXISTS ELSE ORDER BY users.id
```

something like the above statement, if column doesnt exist order by id like the defulat order.

Comment: It's not possible unless you build the query in code and use `EXEC` in a stored procedure

Comment: I see, would this work if I select the column names and and try to match the column to order by, with the results of the column names subselect?

Comment: Basically, I don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: "the user has the option to create his own columns for each table" ? Is this a good idea?

Comment: I'm validating the column creation but I cant see how to implement this, for now i'm doing 2 queries 1 to get the column names.

Comment: I hope this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550942/can-you-add-an-if-statement-in-order-by