# Mysql: Reorder results based on multiple column values then date

Tags: mysql

This is mytable:

```
id | state   | orderid | name  | date
1  | Hold    | 121212  | Mike  | 2018-04-11
2  | Closed  | 121213  | Homer | 2018-04-12
3  | Open    | 121214  | Mike  | 2018-04-13
4  | Hold    | 121215  | Bart  | 2018-04-14
5  | Open    | 121216  | Lisa  | 2018-04-15
6  | Closed  | 121217  | Bart  | 2018-04-16
7  | Closed  | 121218  | Homer | 2018-04-17
```

I'm trying to order by state (open, hold, close), then date (ASC), if the state is "closed", then date (DESC). So a result like this.

```
id | state   | orderid | name  | date
3  | Open    | 121214  | Mike  | 2018-04-13
5  | Open    | 121216  | Lisa  | 2018-04-15
1  | Hold    | 121212  | Mike  | 2018-04-11
4  | Hold    | 121215  | Bart  | 2018-04-14
7  | Closed  | 121218  | Homer | 2018-04-17
6  | Closed  | 121217  | Bart  | 2018-04-16
2  | Closed  | 121213  | Homer | 2018-04-12
```

This is the query I have now:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY FIELD(state,'Open','Hold','Closed') ASC, o_date DESC
```

Have attempted to add the examples given here: [Can you add an if statement in ORDER BY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550942/can-you-add-an-if-statement-in-order-by)
but I'm not getting the results I want.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
ORDER BY FIELD(state,'Open','Hold','Closed') ASC, 
CASE WHEN state = 'Closed' THEN date END DESC,
date ASC
```