# IF in ORDER BY sql php

Tags: php, sql

Hey guys I am not sure if this can be done. I have a table with products like this: [image]

each product has a category and some have a secondary category.

I want to be able to short in this case using the example table above the 'someother' category by `Order2` and `Οrder` for example:

Item2 has as a main category the 'someother' category and order number "2"

Items 1 and 5 have 'someother' category as 2ndcategory with order2 -number "3" and "1"

To display the items I am using the following query:

```
$query= "SELECT * FROM products WHERE category = $cat_id or 2ndcategory = $cat_id  ORDER BY order ASC";
```

As it is right now I am displaying the items with main or 2nd category someother but the display order is item1, item2 and item5

I want to be able to display item5, item2 and item1 using in the case of items 5 and 1 order2 and in the case of item2 order.

I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$query3 = "SELECT * FROM products";
        $tests= $conn->query($query3);
        foreach($tests as $test){
            $test_cat = $test['2ndcategory'];
            $test_id = $test['order2'];
            $test_id_1 = $test['order1'];
            $test_code='';
                if($test_cat != NULL){
                    $test_code = $test_id;
                }else{$test_code = $test_id_1;
              }
            }
$query= "SELECT * FROM products WHERE category = $prod_id or 2ndcategory= $prod_id ORDER BY ".$test_code." ASC";
```

I have also  tried

```
  $query3 = "SELECT * FROM products";
            $tests= $conn->query($query3);
            foreach($tests as $test){
                $test_code= $test['order2'];
                }

    $query= "SELECT * FROM products WHERE category = $prod_id or 2ndcategory= $prod_id ORDER BY IF($test_code != NULL){order2}else{order} ASC";
```

and

```
   $query= "SELECT * FROM products WHERE category = $prod_id or 2ndcategory= $prod_id ORDER BY 
    CASE orderby 
    WHEN order2 != NULL THEN order2
    WHEN  order2 == NULL THEN  order END 
    ASC";
```

I have also tried

```
ORDER BY        
CASE orderby        
WHEN order2 is not NULL THEN order2
ELSE  order END ASC";
```

and

```
ORDER BY 
CASE orderby WHEN order2 is not NULL THEN order2
CASE WHEN order2 is NULL THEN order
ELSE order END 
ASC
```

Any ideas would be great guys. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Mech what do you mean mate this is a php question so the tag is php

Comment: `ORDER BY
CASE WHEN order2 is not NULL THEN order2  END ASC,
CASE WHEN order2 is NULL THEN order END ASC,`

Comment: when you need comparision with `null` then use `is null` not use `=`

Comment: @DevsiOdedra it doesn't seem to work. IT displays 2-1-3 in  this example

Comment: Your description of what sorting you actually want to achieve here, is completely undecipherable to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your description of what kind of sorting your after does not really make sense and this question is also more of an SQL question than a PHP one, however I think this question might be useful:

[Can you add an if statement in ORDER BY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550942/can-you-add-an-if-statement-in-order-by)

Comment: I did see that and did try it but it does not seem to work for me, as nothing appears, `ORDER BY 
  CASE orderby
  WHEN eb_prod_code_sec is not NULL THEN eb_prod_code_sec  ELSE  eb_prod_code END ASC";`

Comment: I also tried it as `ORDER BY CASE orderby WHEN eb_prod_code_sec is not NULL THEN eb_prod_code_sec CASE WHEN eb_prod_code_sec is NULL THEN eb_prod_code ELSE eb_prod_code END ASC` @Kieran

Comment: I managed to make it work,
`Using the following link you can solve it by 

    ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN order2 IS NULL THEN order 
    ELSE order2 END 
    ASC`